# How to solve pattern in one line

Tags: python

I have been trying a lot to print below output using one line

Its a task for me. The below output is in `int`

```
1
121
12321
1234321
123454321
```

**My code :**

```
n=5
lst = []
for i in range(0,n):
    lst.append(i+1)
    print(*lst+lst[::-1][1:],sep='')
```

I cannot use the `str` or `join` and even code of lines should not be more then 2 lines

How to achieve it ?

Comment: `for n in range(5): print(*range(1, n+2), *range(n, 0, -1), sep='')`.  It's bad style IMO to scrunch that onto one line, but it is syntactically valid and will give you the output you want.

Comment: `print('\n'.join((lambda n: [''.join(str(j) for j in (*range(1, i + 1), *range(i - 1, 0, -1))) for i in range(1, n + 1)])(n = 5)))`

Comment: The real question here is, why would you want to solve something like this in one line? However you solve this (in one line), the code will be for sure neither easily understandable nor easily readable.

Comment: "even code of lines should not be more then 2 lines" makes no sense. I think you're trying to achieve this with no more than two lines of code. Why? What's the point? You're clearly new to Python so don't try running before you can walk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the formula `((10**i - 1) // 9) ** 2`

Using for loop

```
n = int(input())
for i in range(1, n+1):print(((10 ** i-1) // 9) ** 2)
```

Approach 2

```
n = int(input())
[print(((10**i - 1) // 9) ** 2) for i in range(1, n + 1)]
```

Comment: loop should start from 0 to n

Comment: @memotib827 Can you clearly explain your question? As per your question you want the required output in two lines. `n` can be any range

Comment: @Sai Manoj : Its a hacker rank question : Triangle quest 2 :  palindrome pattern printing ...your code gives string luteral error. Not able to submit

Comment: @SaiManoj : Try this question  https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/triangle-quest-2/problem   ... your answer is right but not accepted as it throws invalid literal error

Comment: @memotib827 check now. Make sure no spaces added in lines. It should be in line 1 and line 2